# Material SearchView Compat in Toolbar

Tags: android

When I add a SearchView Compat to a toolbar, it shows text and icons in black, not in white. When I add it to an ActionBar, I got it to be white.
My toolbar is set as follows

```
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/LightApplicationTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
        app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
        app:contentInsetEndWithActions="0dp"
        app:theme="@style/LightApplicationTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        app:popupTheme="@style/LightApplicationTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

My application theme extends `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`, and in styles I have the following;

```
    <style name="LightApplicationTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
</style>

<style name="LightApplicationTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
</style>
```

I know I can add `<item name="searchViewStyle">@style/SearchViewStyle</item>` to the Application style (not the toolbar style), and then in `SearchViewStyle` I can set the following;

```
<style name="SearchViewStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.SearchView">
<!-- Background for the search query section (e.g. EditText) -->
<!-- <item name="queryBackground">@android:color/black</item> -->
<!-- Background for the actions section (e.g. voice, submit) -->
<!-- <item name="submitBackground">...</item> -->
<!-- Close button icon -->
<!-- <item name="closeIcon">...</item> -->
<!-- Search button icon -->
<!-- <item name="searchIcon">...</item> -->
<!-- Go/commit button icon -->
<!-- <item name="goIcon">...</item> -->
<!-- Voice search button icon -->
<!-- <item name="voiceIcon">...</item> -->
<!-- Commit icon shown in the query suggestion row -->
<!-- <item name="commitIcon">...</item> -->
<!-- Layout for query suggestion rows -->
<!-- <item name="suggestionRowLayout">...</item> -->
</style>
```

but I have no idea how to change text color, and dropdown color.
Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I got it done using some (dirty) code.
Here it is;

```
mSearchView = new SearchView(this);
....
applyColorToAllViews(mSearchView, Color.WHITE);
```

And here is the function that does it;

```
private void applyColorToAllViews(ViewGroup group, @ColorInt int tintColor)
{
    int count = group.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        View v = group.getChildAt(i);
        if (v instanceof ViewGroup)
        {
            applyColorToAllViews((ViewGroup)v, tintColor);
        }
        else if (v instanceof ImageView)
        {
            ImageView iv = (ImageView)v;
            Drawable drawable = iv.getDrawable();
            if (drawable != null)
            {
                DrawableCompat.setTint(drawable, tintColor);
                iv.setImageDrawable(drawable);
            }
        }
        else if (v instanceof TextView)
        {
            TextView tv = (TextView)v;
            tv.setTextColor(tintColor);
            tv.setHintTextColor(0x80000000 | (tintColor & 0xFFFFFF));
        }
    }
}
```